# Google App Engine and Google Earth Engine in Windows

Tags: google-app-engine, google-earth-engine

I am trying to test a basic app with Google App Engine using the trendy-lights example with Google Earth Engine App.

I cloned the trendy-lights app from the GEE github repository and updated the application name in app.yaml, EE_ACCOUNT in config.py and the privatekey.pem file. I didn't do any other change. However the trendy-lights app does not work.

I am trying to run this on MS Windows 7 and when I run it I get an error Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

I have looked through examples and I can see people have got this working through Linux but not Windows. Has anyone got this working?

Answer (score 0):

You need at least to post some logs.

Make sure you account is whitelisted: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/service_account#register-the-service-account-to-use-earth-engine.

I could not get the current version of trendy-lights on Windows either, it requires bash to install requirements (`build.sh`). But even after installing all requirements it did not work, it looks like `oauth2client` requires a few more libraries. I think in flex app engine environment handling dependencies is easier.

... I've added a PowerShell script to install trendy-lights dependencies, you can find the script here: https://github.com/gena/earthengine-api/blob/master/demos/trendy-lights/build.ps1

Then, make sure you've installed the latest version of gcloud tools and all required app engine extensions (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download). Also, make sure you use Python 2.7, I think `dev_appserver.py` requires that. When using Anaconda, you can create a new environment for Python 2.7 for that.